# Minimal pairs for Mongolian

Tags: mongolian, minimal-pairs

What minimal pairs are available for a native speaker of English learning Mongolian? Ideally, they should be based on real words, have spelling in Mongolian Cyrillic available, and have pronunciation sound files for each particular word.

The closest I've found so far is [Lesson One: Introduction to Mongolian Cyrillic](http://www.themongolist.com/language-resources/beginner-mongolian/lesson-one-introduction-to-mongolian-cyrillic.html) on The Mongolist website, referred to by the [Fluent Forever Forum](https://fluent-forever.com/forums/topic/mongolist/).

Answer (score 4):

The book "Colloquial Mongolian" has a short list of minimal pairs for vowels on page 13. The pronunciation for them is available at approximately 12:30 on track one of their free [audio download](http://www.routledgetextbooks.com/textbooks/colloquial/mongolian.php).

It gives the following pairs as examples, though not necessarily in this order:

> зуу/зүү
>   олон/өлөн
>   ус/үс
>   ул/үл
>   уул/үүл